Can one naturally transform Tamari lattices into distributive lattices with the same number of elements?
Many of the zillions of combinatorial objects counted by Catalan numbers come with various lattice structures.
The $n$th Tamari lattice $T_n$, as originally defined, is the lattice of all those maps $f:\{1,...,n\}\to\{1,...,n\}$ which satisfy the conditions

$i\leqslant f(i)$;

if $i\leqslant j\leqslant f(i)$ then $f(j)\leqslant f(i)$,


for all $i,j\in\{1,...,n\}$, ordered valuewise, i. e. by declaring $f\leqslant g$ iff $f(i)\leqslant g(i)$ for all $i\in\{1,...,n\}$. The Hasse diagram of $T_n$ is the edge graph of the $n+1$st associahedron, tilted in a certain tricky way. Here is $T_4$ for example:

(I have omitted the last numbers of node labels, they are all $4$.)
The lattice $D_n$ of all inflationary order preserving maps $f:\{1,...,n\}\to\{1,...,n\}$, that is, maps satisfying

$i\leqslant f(i)$;

if $i\leqslant j\leqslant f(i)$ then $f(i)\leqslant f(j)$,


again ordered valuewise, has the same number of elements as $T_n$ but looks entirely different. For example, it is always distributive, while $T_n$ is not even modular for $n>2$. Here is the Hasse diagram of $D_4$:

(Last numbers are again omitted, by the same reason.)
Question: is there any natural (e. g. functorial) mapping from finite lattices to finite lattices which carries $T_n$ to $D_n$, or vice versa?
Some remarks which might or might not be relevant.
Intersection of $T_n$ and $D_n$ is the lattice of all closure operators on $\{1,...,n\}$, i. e. order preserving maps $f$ with $i\leqslant f(i)=f(f(i))$. It has $2^{n-1}$ elements and is isomorphic to the powerset of $\{1,...,n-1\}$: to a closure operator $f$ corresponds the subset of strictly $f$-increasing elements, i. e. $\{i\mid f(i)>i\}$, while to a subset $S$ corresponds the operator $f_S$ given by $f_S(i)=\min\{j\mid i\leqslant j\notin S\}$.
On the other hand, both $T_n$ and $D_n$ are embedded in the lattice $I_n$ of all inflationary operators, that is, maps $f$ with $i\leqslant f(i)$ for all $i$ - $D_n$ as a sublattice but $T_n$ only as a meet-subsemilattice. $I_n$ is distributive, it has $n!$ elements and is isomorphic to the lattice product
$$
(1<2<3<\dots<n)\times(2<3<\dots<n)\times\cdots\times(n-1<n)
$$
of linear orders. It is thus also natural to ask whether there is an operation that transforms the lattice $P_n$ of permutations of $\{1,...,n\}$ under the weak order into $I_n$. Like $T_n$, $P_n$ is not modular for $n>2$. Note that the Hasse diagram of $P_n$ is the edge graph of a permutohedron.

I can make some partial progress. There is a standard bijection between permutations and Lehmer codes https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lehmer_code . A Lehmer code is a map $g : [n] \to \mathbb{Z}$ with $0 \leq g(i) \leq n-i$; if $g$ is a Lehmer code then $f(i) := i+g(i)$ is an inflationary map. So that gives a bijection between $I_n$ and $S_n$. I believe that, under your definitions, $T_n$ corresponds to 312 avoiding permutations and $D_n$ corresponds to 231 avoiding permutations. These are easy to biject with each other -- just conjugate by $w_0$.

So this explains why $|D_n| = |T_n|$, and even why this stays true if we keep track of $\sum f(i)$, since this corresponds to the length of the permutation (plus $\binom{n}{2}$).

Very valuable information, thank you!

But this doesn't explain the statements about the poset structure. I am used to thinking of $T_n$ as the partial order induced on $312$ avoiding permutations by weak order on $S_n$. Your termwise comparison on Lehmer codes isn't the same as weak order -- it is strictly stronger. Maybe what is going on is that, for some reason, your order and weak order have the same restriction to $312$-avoiding permutations, but very different restrictions to $231$ avoiding permutations?

Well, orders on $I_n$ and $P_n$ are also radically different. But somehow I think they might be easier to transform, maybe because $I_n$ is easier than $D_n$ and $P_n$ easier than $T_n$...

The $I_n$ order is a strengthening of the weak order (and a weakening of the strong order). I don't know what you mean by a way of transforming one to another.

PS $D_n$ is also the lattice of partitions sitting inside the staircase $(n-1, n-2, \dots, 2,1)$, ordered by reverse containment.

Well, I don't know it myself actually. I should probably include my original motivation but it is a long story. There is a 1-1 correspondence between multiplicative closure operators $j$ on a complete Heyting algebra and operators of the form $f(x)=j(x)\to x$, where $\to$ is the Heyting implication. The latter are idempotent and inflationary but not order preserving, instead they satisfy $\bigwedge_if(x_i)\le f(\bigwedge_ix_i)$ and $f(x)\le f(y\to x)$.

I am after an extension of this correspondence to unknown broader class on the $j$ side and those $f$ which only satisfy $x\le fx$, $x\leftrightarrow y\le fx\leftrightarrow fy$ and $(x\to y)\land(y\to fx)\land fy\le fx$. When the algebra is $(1<...<n)$ such more general $f$ are precisely elements of $T_n$.

FWIW, the distributive lattice of partitions inside a staircase shape is sometimes called the “Stanley lattice.” And there is also a 3rd important lattice on Catalan objects, namely the lattice of noncrosssing set partitions (first studied by Kreweras). I think there are papers studying lattices “between” these three, but I don’t know if any of them address your particular question.

The lattice $D_n$ is also known as the lattice of Dyck paths. It is isomorphic to the lattice of congruences of the Tamari lattice. Even if it is not written explicitly, this can be found in the article On Tamari lattices of Geyer.
One can also perfom a strange deformation of the Tamari lattice and find the lattice of Dyck path. This is explained in the article  Linear Intervals in the Tamari and the Dyck Lattices and in the alt-Tamari Posets by Chenevière.

@BaptisteRognerud Many thanks for these references! Description of join- and meet-irreducibles by Geyer is indeed crucial, as well as semidistributivity and especially congruence lattice. Also the work of Chenevière looks very interesting, except so far I cannot locate that strange deformation - in fact there is no word "deformation" there.

Oh I found it - Chenevière defines another partial order on Dyck paths for each binary word of length $n$, with $D_n$ corresponding to $00..0$ and $T_n$ to $11...1$. You mean this under strange deformation, right?

@DavidESpeyer Can you provide an example of "my" order being strictly stronger than weak order on $312$ avoiding permutations? I don't know how to check lattice isomorphism, but up to $n=5$ the Hasse diagrams have the same number of edges.

Yes exactly, I like to see these new posets as intermediate deformations between the Tamari lattice and the lattice of Dyck path. Of course this is very specific to this example.

@DavidESpeyer I now checked up to $n=5$, indeed (except that $312$ and $231$ seem to be swapped) on permutations $\sigma$ which avoid $\sigma(i_3)<\sigma(i_1)<\sigma(i_2)$ for $i_1<i_2<i_3$ the ordering induced by the termwise ordering of their Lehmer codes gives the Tamari lattices, while on permutations avoiding $\sigma(i_2)<\sigma(i_3)<\sigma(i_1)$ for $i_1<i_2<i_3$ the same ordering gives the $D_n$ lattice.
